# GDB in Visual Studio Code Debugging bar disabled

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

- I am trying to debug Assembly x86 in Visual Studio Code but all the stepping buttons are disabled
- I am using this extension `https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DamianKoper.gdb-debug`
- I am using Windows 7 and i have installed `gdb` with `Msys`
- This is `launch.json` :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [      
        {
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "GDB",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${command:AskForProgramName}",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "arguments": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same issue with GDB Debug extension in VS Code (WSL2), also tried change configs with no result. Anyhow, this extension and similar extensions (like Native Debug that allowed me to make breakpoints with proper config) are not so useful. There is no register view and memory view that are crucial for asm debugging. I assume VS Code is not good for asm, and for Windows your best bets are QtCreator (includes asm debugger with registers, etc) and MS Visual Studio. Another option is GDB in TUI mode from the terminal (gdb ./exefilename -tui), but GDB with its number of commands has a steep learning curve.